# Communication between consul on local VM and consul in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, consul

I have a Kubernetes cluster with 2 master nodes and 3 worker nodes. I have used HELM to install consul setup which has 3 consul-servers and 5 consul-clients running.

Here is how the consul server pods and consul client pods are placed on the Kubernetes nodes:

```sh
[root@k8masterg2m1 autoinstall]# kubectl get po -o wide | grep consul
consul-consul-4lxtr 1/1 Running 0 103m 192.168.139.139 k8masterg2m1
consul-consul-6wv9w 1/1 Running 0 103m 192.168.118.215 k8workerg2w3
consul-consul-pc562 1/1 Running 0 103m 192.168.108.162 k8workerg2w2
consul-consul-server-0 1/1 Running 0 107m 192.168.118.214 k8workerg2w3
consul-consul-server-1 1/1 Running 0 9m15s 192.168.227.91 k8workerg2w1
consul-consul-server-2 1/1 Running 0 107m 192.168.108.161 k8workerg2w2
consul-consul-tg4kz 1/1 Running 0 103m 192.168.139.72 k8masterg2m2
consul-consul-tj7h5 1/1 Running 0 103m 192.168.227.90 k8workerg2w1
```

On the other side I have installed consul client on a local VM, which is on the same networks as the Kubernetes nodes.

From the consul server pods running in Kubernetes, I have used the below command to join the local VM(10.0.20.102).

```sh
/ # consul join 10.0.20.102
Successfully joined cluster by contacting 1 nodes.
```

I could see the below output in both the VM and consul pods in the Kubernetes:

```sh
/ # consul members

Node Address Status Type Build Protocol DC Segment
consul-consul-server-0 192.168.118.214:8301 alive server 1.8.1 2 dc1
consul-consul-server-1 192.168.227.91:8301 alive server 1.8.1 2 dc1
consul-consul-server-2 192.168.108.161:8301 alive server 1.8.1 2 dc1
k8masterg1m2 10.0.20.102:8301 alive client 1.8.1 2 dc1
k8masterg2m1 192.168.139.139:8301 alive client 1.8.1 2 dc1
k8masterg2m2 192.168.139.72:8301 alive client 1.8.1 2 dc1
k8workerg2w1 192.168.227.90:8301 alive client 1.8.1 2 dc1
k8workerg2w2 192.168.108.162:8301 alive client 1.8.1 2 dc1
k8workerg2w3 192.168.118.215:8301 alive client 1.8.1 2 dc1
```

Now, when I try to list the services in Kubernetes consul pods it works fine as shown below:

```sh
/ # consul catalog services

consul
consul-consul-dns-default
consul-consul-server-default
consul-consul-ui-default
ha-rabbitmq-rabbitmq-ha-default
ha-rabbitmq-rabbitmq-ha-discovery-default
kubernetes-default
vault-agent-injector-svc-default
vault-internal-default
```

but, when I try to run the same command in local VM it gives the below error:

```sh
[root@k8masterg1m2 autoinstall]# consul catalog services
Error listing services: Unexpected response code: 500 (rpc error getting client: failed to get conn: rpc error: lead thread didn’t get connection)
```

Since on the consul agent running in the local VM, it is able to list the members but not services/nodes.
Is this the expected behavior or is there any other configuration which has to be done to get this work.

Also, I wanted to know how the communication happens between consul servers and consul agent which is outside Kubernetes cluster.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 3):

It's an odd setup that you want to join the VM. But for everything to work you need to make sure that [all the required ports](https://www.consul.io/docs/install/ports) are exposed on the Consul Server nodes. It sounds like all of those ports are exposed within the Kubernetes cluster but not outside.

You didn't specify how you deployed Consul but you can use [Kubernetes Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) to expose the ports. In your case, it's likely that maybe port `8500` is the only exposed from your VM but maybe not the other ports. You have to expose them all if you'd like to enable all the Consul features/functionality.

✌️